# Openrecordset With Multiple Tables, Access 2016

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am getting an "Object variable or With block variable not set (Error 91)" error with the following code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim mySQL As String
    mySQL = "SELECT Tuteurs.ID_Tuteur, Tarifs_17_18.*, Paiements_17_18.* " & _
            "FROM (Tuteurs INNER JOIN Tarifs_17_18 ON Tuteurs.ID_Tuteur = Tarifs_17_18.TuteurID_Trf) " & _
            "INNER JOIN Paiements_17_18 ON Tuteurs.ID_Tuteur = Paiements_17_18.TuteurID_Pmt " & _
            "WHERE ID_Tuteur =" & [Forms]![Eleves]![TuteurID_Elv]

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(mySQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    rs.MoveFirst
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Enregistrer_Click()

    Dim totIns As Integer
    totIns = DSum("Montant", "Paiements_17_18", "[Mois_Regle]='Inscription'")

    If totIns = rs!Tarif_Inscription Then
        MsgBox "Yes" & totIns & " = " & rs!Tarif_Inscription
    Else
        MsgBox "No" & totIns & " # " & rs!Tarif_Inscription
    End If
End Sub
```

`totIns` is working very well but `rs!Tarif_Inscription` is the missing object variable.

`[Tarif_Inscription]` is a field in the `[Tarifs_17_18]` Table.

Any Help Please?

Comment: just looks like you need to remove the () around `(Tuteurs INNER JOIN Tarifs_17_18 ON Tuteurs.ID_Tuteur = Tarifs_17_18.TuteurID_Trf)`

Comment: Try removing `dbSeeChanges`.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Solution,
My recordset is not in scope and My variables are declared outside My procedure.
Solution found by @Moke123.